# Reset vTiger 5.4 password

Tags: passwords, mysql, reset, vtiger-crm

A while ago I installed vTiger on a server for a co-worker. He forgot his password and asked me to reset it. There are some threads out there telling you how to reset the password on older versions of vTiger, but it seems like they changed from md5 hashes to something that looks like BCrypt.

Does anyone know how to reset the password? I do have access to the database.

Comment: What version of MySQL was vTiger using ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA It's a MySQL 5.1 server.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to database. please try to reset password using this sql script. This will reset password to "admin"

`update vtiger_users set user_password = 'adpexzg3FUZAk', crypt_type = '' where user_name = 'your_user_name';`

Comment: I tried this already, but this only works with older versions of vTiger apparently.